# Writing generics to file

Tags: generics, file-io, rust

I would like to write a generic type to disk. Something like:

```
fn write_to_file<T: SomeTrait>(item: T, f: File) {
    f.write(item.to_bytes());
}
```

where `SomeTrait` and `to_bytes` are made up. What trait does the type need to implement, and how can I turn an element of that type into a form which I can write to a `Writer` object?

The `Encodable` trait seems promising, but the only `Encoder` I see is one for JSON.

Edit: I'm also looking for a way to *read* generics from file (or any stream of bytes), in case the answer is similar to writing.

Comment: You may well be best to have that trait take a `Writer` instead and write to it on its own terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no way to just write a value of some *arbitrary* type to a disk. You should choose some serialization strategy, and some strategies which would work for one type won't work for another.

For example, you could choose just to write the memory dump of the structure contents (with a bit of unsafe conversions):

```
use std::mem;
use std::raw;
use std::io::IoResult;

fn dump<T, W: Writer>(item: &T, writer: &mut W) -> IoResult<()> {
    let slice: &[u8] = unsafe {
        mem::transmute(raw::Slice {
            data: item as *const _ as *const u8,
            len: mem::size_of::<T>()
        })
    };
    writer.write(slice)
}
```

This would hastily break for types which contain pointers, however. Serializing a type like

```
struct SomeStruct {
    data: Vec<String>
}
```

with this method does not make sense - it would write just those bytes which represent the `Vec`, which is a pointer, a length and a capacity, not the actual data. Naturally, you won't be able to deserialize such structure back. To make this function useful, you will have to restrict it only to types which are both `Copy` (their semantic copy is plain `memcpy`) and `Send` (sendable between tasks; in this particular case it would exclude structs which contain shared references, which are `Copy`):

```
fn dump<T: Copy+Send, W: Writer>(item: &T, writer: W) -> IoResult<()> { ... }
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to exclude structures with `&'static` references and raw poitners. Both of these are unsafe to serialize and deserialize, but there seems to be no type system mechanism to exclude them.

In order to serialize more complex structures with pointers, you *will* need some trait like `Encodable` which is intelligent enough to support arbitrary types. Mere `Encodable` is not enough, however, because you still need some *concrete strategy* of serialization. How do you represent a `Vec`, for example? You can't just dump its byte representation, so you need to read the vector *contents* and store them somehow into the output stream, probably in such way so they could be deserialized later. That's why `Encodable` is paired with `Encoder`: `Encodable` implementation "describes" its structure to an `Encoder`, which is able to store this structure to a byte stream in some format.

So in order to reliably serialize some type, you need at least to implement an [`Encoder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/trait.Encoder.html) for your specific serialization strategy and have your type implement `Encodable` (which in most cases can be done automatically with `#[deriving(Encodable)]` attribute). There is one implementation of `Encoder`s in standard library, [`json::Encoder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/struct.Encoder.html); if you know your serialization format, you can use `json::Encoder` as an reference implementation.

In order to deserialize some type, you need to implement a [`Decoder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/trait.Decoder.html) for the same serialization strategy and have your type implement `Decodable` (again, in most cases it is automatic with `#[deriving(Decodable)]`). There is a decoder in the standard library, [`json::Decoder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/struct.Decoder.html), which transforms [`Json`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/enum.Json.html) instance to a value of type which implements `Decodable`.

Note that `Json` encoding and decoding is somewhat asymmetric. Encoding is performed directly: `T: Encodable -> byte data`, while decoding is a two step process: `byte data -> Json -> T: Decodable`. This may be unnecessary for your serialization strategy.

There are libraries which provide encoders for various serialization formats, for example, [rust-msgpack](https://github.com/mneumann/rust-msgpack). You can find one which would suit your needs or write something yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. For my needs, I think the `Copy` type is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Note that it is also highly platform-dependent (forgot to mention it in the text). For example, if you serialize a structure on 64-bit system, on 32-bit system your program may fail to deserialize it properly due to `uint`/`int` size difference (and possibly different structure layout).

Comment: Please note that I updated my answer to include `Send` in addition to `Copy`. This is needed to exclude references from allowed types. But still it isn't fully safe...